# Using Material-UI theme colors in CSS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, material-ui

Is it possible to use styles from the Material-UI theme in a .css or .module.css file? For instance, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
.barChart {
   fill: theme.pallete.primary.main
}
```

I'm using the d3 SVG component to create a bar chart and I need the fill value for each bar to be based on the colors from the theme. So eventually, my goal is to do something like this:

```
 g.selectAll('rect')
        .data(this.props.data)
        .classed("barChart", true)
        ...
```

For some reason, using makeStyle classes does not work with d3. For such a simple task, I've been searching for hours and could not find a solution.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I am in the same case as you.

Comment: @Ismael Unfortunately, no!! I ended up hardcoding the colors based on my theme colors. :\